# Pandas - Replace missing values & simultaneously add prefix or suffix based on column?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to pre-process some data for machine learning purposes. I'm currently trying to clean up some NaN values and replace them with 'unknown' and a prefix or suffix which is based on the column name.

The reason for this is when I'm use one hot encoding, I can't have multiple columns with the same name being fed into xgboost.

So what I have is the following

```
df = df.apply(lambda x: x.replace(np.nan, 'unknown'))
```

And I'd like to replace all instances of NaN in the df with 'unknown_columname'. Is there any easy or simple way to do this?

Comment: Try `df = df.apply(lambda x: x.replace(np.nan, f'unknown_{x.name}'))`. You can also use `df = df.apply(lambda x: x.fillna(f'unknown_{x.name}'))`

Comment: This is perfect and goes along well with my code! If you submit this as an answer, I'd like to give you the points!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `df = df.apply(lambda x: x.replace(np.nan, f'unknown_{x.name}'))`.

You can also use `df = df.apply(lambda x: x.fillna(f'unknown_{x.name}')`.

Answer (score 1):

First let's create the backup array to be filled whenever we have a missing value

```
s = np.core.defchararray.add('unknown',df.columns.values)
```

Then we can simply replace each NaN with the right value from s:

```
cols = df.columns.values
for col_name in cols:
    df.col_name.fillna(s, inplace=True)
```